# How can android get location updates with no internet connection and no sim card

Tags: android, gps, location

I am using the following code to get new location updates on an android app. But i noticed it gives location updates even when the wifi is turned off and sim card taken out. so how can that be? how can location update with no network or internet access

```
                 locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                  locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
                    {
                        Log.d("jdks", " " + " location updated")
                        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                    }

                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
                    {
                    }

                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
                    {
                    }

                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
                    {                 
                    }
                };

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Comment: [`LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#GPS_PROVIDER) – "This provider determines location using satellites." Your device's GPS receiver is a completely separate thing from the Wi-Fi and mobile networks.

Comment: @Mike M , Thank you, that is something i didn't know. i assume you are talking about the GPS provider. so how about the network provider, does it use the network it gets from the sim card or does it use regular internet connection.

Comment: "i assume you are talking about the GPS provider." – Yes, that's why I linked to and quoted the documentation for `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`. "so how about the network provider, does it use the network it gets from the sim card or does it use regular internet connection." – If you consult the documentation for [`LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#NETWORK_PROVIDER), you'll see that it explains that it "determines location based on availability of cell tower and WiFi access points", so it's a combination of both.

Comment: Thank you, made perfect sense, but i just tried getting a location update only using network provider on a device that has no sim card and no wifi connection and i still get updates, do you know why? kinda doesn't fit with what the documentation says about network providers.